# Fetch returns an array-like with type undefined. How do I get the data inside it?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I need to use this JSON returned from server via fetch to build HTML but I don't know how to access just the guys' names from it.

```
Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
fetch(URL)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))

/*logs:
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {title: "Patrick"}
1: {title: "Ben"}
2: {title: "Jeffree"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
*/

.then(function(data) {
    console.log(typeof data); //undefined
    let arr = Array.from(data); //Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert
                                //undefined or null to object
})
```

At first I tried to iterate over it as it (`data`) looked like an array but got `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`. 
Is this an async problem and that's why `data` is undefined? I figured that since it gets logged alright it should already be resolved by the time I try to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` returns `undefined`. You need to return `data` after logging so that the promise resolved with the `data` not with `undefined`

```
fetch(URL)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {console.log(data); return data})
.then(data => {
  console.log(typeof data)
})
```

```js
Promise.resolve(1).then(console.log).then(x => console.log(1, typeof x))

Promise.resolve(2).then(tap).then(x => console.log(2, typeof x))

function tap(x) {
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}
```